# Webpack - relative SCSS imports with Storyboard

Tags: webpack, sass, storybook

The relative imports of my `scss` files are not working on [storybook's](https://storybook.js.org) webpack configuration. The Webpack configuration for the actual app is working fine.

Here is my project structure:

```
-- project
  |-- .storybook
  |  |-- webpack.config.js
  |
  |-- src
  |  |-- assets
  |  |  |-- styles.scss   // @import './_table'
  |  |  |-- _table.scss
  |  |
  |  |-- index.js .      // import './assets/style.scss'
  |
  |-- story
  |  |-- story.index.js  // import '../src/assets/styles.scss' - HERE `_table.scss` not working
  |
  |-- webpack.config.js
```

It seems the `./_table.scss` relative import of my main `styles.scss` is not being loaded, as the styling seems wrong when rendering the component.

Here are both webpack config:

**project's one**

```
...
entry: [
  './src/index.js'
],
...
  {  
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
  }
```

**storybook's one**

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
  },
```

**The import that is not working is:**

```
// <root>/src/assets/styles.scss
@import './_table'
```

Is there anything I'm missing on why the relative import it's not working? Or do you need more info on my Webpack config? (I don't think there's anything else helpful)

Comment: did you manage to get this sorted?

Comment: Yes. The problem was that my CSS styles were defined under a div that used a `my-class` class. I didn't put that class on the storyboard so the style was not loading. Very silly mistake.